# ASP.NET Web API 2 - Nested Object in Ajax Post coming across as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to write a MVC/Web API page, and am stuck on the Web API post portion when doing more than just base types. I cannot seem to find an answer why the Roles object keeps getting set to null even though it's posting from the client side (and it's passing the ModelState.IsValid portion?)

If I take all the code out that relates to the Roles portion, it works and the user gets created in the database.

Edit: Changing [FromUri] to [FromBody] combined with adding Bracket around Roles data seemed to do it. Other errors popping up but able to take it from there. Thanks.

The defined model:

```
public class ExpandedUser
{

        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Lockout End Date UTC")]
        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserRoles> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateUser([FromUri] ExpandedUser user)

    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        } else if (user.Roles == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


        /*var roleId = user.Roles.ToList();

       var role = _context.Roles.Select(c => new
       {
           Id = c.Id,
           Name = c.Name,
           Users = c.Users
       }).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == roleId.RoleName);*/



        var newUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email =  user.Email,
            PasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user.Password)

    };


        try
        {
            _context.Users.Add(newUser);
            /*userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, role.Name);*/
            _context.SaveChanges();


        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

And the AJAX call:

```
  var payload = {
            Id: 0, UserName: $('#username').val(),
            Email: $('#email').val(),
            Password: $('#password').val(),
            LockoutEndDateUtc: null,
            AccessFailedCount :0,
            Roles: {
            RoleName: $('#role').val()
        }
        };
        payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
        console.log(payload);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/api/CreateUser",
            data: payload,
            success: function (data) {
                redir();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },
            dataType: "json",
        });
```

Comment: Since you do `[HttpPost]` - may be you should define the parameter `[FromBody]` like following: 
    `public IHttpActionResult CreateUser([FromBody] ExpandedUser user)` instead

Comment: What if you change from `IEnumerable<UserRoles>` to `UserRoles[]`?  I mean serialization is supposed to render a concrete object.  IEnumerable serializes to the server as what?  A list, array, HashSet....?

Comment: Well, changing to [FromBody] got past the Roles = null problem. But now I'm getting a An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code that I'll need to figure out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define your payload object as follow (note the Roles become array property:

```
var payload = {
            Id: 0, UserName: $('#username').val(),
            Email: $('#email').val(),
            Password: $('#password').val(),
            LockoutEndDateUtc: null,
            AccessFailedCount :0,
            Roles: [{
            RoleName: $('#role').val()
        }]
        };
```

Comment: Added the brackets to Roles, but it's still coming across as null and hitting the NotFound I put in for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Changing [FromUri] to [FromBody] combined with adding Bracket around Roles data seemed to do it. Other errors popping up but able to take it from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firslty, you should remove `FromUri` because you are applying a post request and putting the json data in the body. So, there is no coming data from uri. Besides you can't pass a complex object via Uri.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateUser(ExpandedUser user);
```

Then modify the Javascript object. The `Roles` expects a collection;

```
var payload = {
            Id: 0, UserName: $('#username').val(),
            Email: $('#email').val(),
            Password: $('#password').val(),
            LockoutEndDateUtc: null,
            AccessFailedCount :0,
            Roles: [{ RoleName: $('#role').val()}]
        };
```